# Detect with "JSON for Modern C++" library that integer doesn't fit into a specified type?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

This code prints `-1`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto jsonText = "{ \"val\" : 4294967295 }";
    auto json = nlohmann::json::parse(jsonText);
    std::cout << json.at("val").get<int>() << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to detect that the value is out of the expected range. Is it possible to accomplish somehow?

Comment: Maybe with `auto v = json.at("val"); if (v.get<int>() != v.get<std::intmax_t>()) { /* range error */ }` or something?

Comment: @Shawn But I don't know the actual value beforehand.

Comment: So? You don't need to.

Comment: @Shawn Ok, I got it now. I hoped for a more straightforward way though.

Comment: @vkrzv I've completely re-written my answer because the first one was horribly wrong, and I added details explaining why Shawn's way is the only way to do it basically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aside Holt's answer, you can also take advantage of the [`operator==`](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a122640e7e2db1814fc7bbb3c122ec76e.html) the library defines, which states:

> **Integer and floating-point numbers are automatically converted before comparison.** Note than two NaN values are always treated as unequal.

What happens here is that the number overflows, which means `json["val"] != json["val"].get<int>()`.<sub>Disclaimer: I have no idea how efficient this approach is compared to Holt's approach</sub>

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto jsonText = "{ \"val\" : 4294967296 }";
    auto json = nlohmann::json::parse(jsonText);
    auto val = json["val"].get<long long>();
    auto i = json["val"].get<int>();
    bool longOverflow = json["val"] != val;
    bool intOverflow = json["val"] != i;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Long: " << longOverflow << "\nInt: " << intOverflow;
}
```

Prints:

```
Long: false
Int: true
```

<sub>[Try it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TwRIu5tQZLTpMHHT)</sub>

Note that this has a caveat: If the value stored in the JSON is a double or a float, and is retrieved as a long or int, it'll naturally evaluate to true (12.3 != 12), but it doesn't have to imply an overflow. You can check the general type with [`is_number_integer()`](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_abac8af76067f1e8fdca9052882c74428.html#abac8af76067f1e8fdca9052882c74428) (checks for int, long, and various other types, unsigned or signed) and [`is_number_float()`](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a33b4bf898b857c962e798fc7f6e86e70.html#a33b4bf898b857c962e798fc7f6e86e70) (checks for double/float).

From what I can tell though, from int/long to double doesn't fail. However, provided a big enough number, [the library will fail to parse the number](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a28f7c2f087274a0012eb7a2333ee1580.html) (`json.exception.out_of_range.406`), so there's a hard limit imposed by the library. From what I can tell, that limit is set at `1.79769e+308` (at least on Wandbox), or the max double value. This also makes double the only type you can't overflow with the library.

As far as automatically checking for number overflow when you retrieve it with a certain type, that's not supported out of the box.

Answer (score 10):

The only way to do what you want is to actually retrieve the value in a larger integer type, and then check if the value is within the range of `int`.

```
using integer_t = nlohmann::json::number_integer_t;
auto ivalue = json.at("val").get<integer_t>();

if (ivalue < std::numeric_limits<int>::min() || ivalue > std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) {
    // Range error... 
}
```

#### Some details...

The number is parsed during the call to `parse()`  using `std::strtoull` or `std::strtoll` (depending on the presence of a `-` sign), and converted to a `nlohmann::json::number_integer_t` (`int64_t`<sup>1</sup>) or `nlohmann::json::number_unsigned_t` (`uint64_t`<sup>1</sup>).

When you query the value with `get<int>`, the only thing done is a cast from the stored `int64_t`/`uint64_t` value to `int`, so there is no way to check the range at this point.

Also, you cannot retrieve the original "string" since only the actual (unsigned) integer value is stored.

<sub><sup>1</sup> `int64_t` and `uint64_t` are the default types since `nlohmann::json` is actually an alias to a `basic_json` template (much like `std::string`), but you can use whatever types you want.</sub>

Comment: Well, I expected a bit more help with such things from such a powerful library.

Comment: @vkrzv You can look at the implementation (https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/include/nlohmann/detail/conversions/from_json.hpp#L41), and you'll see there is no way to perform such check using only the builtins from the library.